# Read Web XML using Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, parsing, web

I'm developing an app to read XML file from the web and parse it into text.
I have tried the following code and it works perfectly with a normal project on eclipse(made slight changes for Android Studio):

```js
package ali.androidtest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void getData(View v)throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
        URL xmlUrl = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dallas%20ga&units=metric&mode=xml");
        System.out.println("hi");
        InputStream in = xmlUrl.openStream();
        Document doc = parse(in);


        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("temperature");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Temperature: " + eElement.getAttribute("value"));


            }
        }
    }
    public static Document parse (InputStream is) {
        Document ret = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory;
        DocumentBuilder builder;

        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setValidating(false);
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            ret = builder.parse(is);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("unable to load XML: " + ex);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

getData is link to a button. 
When I use this code in android studio to develop I get an error:

```js
02-12 23:39:15.757  22930-22930/ali.androidtest I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-12 23:39:15.811  22930-22930/ali.androidtest I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-12 23:39:15.816  22930-22930/ali.androidtest I/System.out﹕ hello
02-12 23:39:15.827  22930-22930/ali.androidtest I/System.out﹕ hi
02-12 23:39:15.840  22930-22930/ali.androidtest D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
02-12 23:39:15.840  22930-22930/ali.androidtest D/libc﹕ getaddrinfo called from pid =22930
02-12 23:39:15.840  22930-22930/ali.androidtest D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
02-12 23:39:15.852  22930-22930/ali.androidtest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-12 23:39:15.866  22930-22930/ali.androidtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ali.androidtest, PID: 22930
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19833)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4010)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19833)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:255)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at ali.androidtest.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.java:32)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4010)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19833)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ali.androidtest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Include your layouts too.

Comment: It might be because of `getData(View v)throws IOException`. There is no space in between of (View v) and throws.

Comment: Nope that's not a problem. I've changed that as well. My layout just has a button.

Comment: Post all your source including layouts. You might made a mistake on that too.

Comment: Not sure what how to get that. I've added android manifest file to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using Async to get the data.